# Saving Coordinates with mapbox in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, mapbox, postgis

I'm trying to make an app, where the user could draw a polygon in the map and save it. I'm using mapbox, ruby on rails and postgis. I can display the map, draw the polygon and capture it's coordinates, buy when trying to create, it throws the following error:
NoMethodError in PoligonosController#create
undefined method `permit' for #String:0x00007f8ba8dbd090.

Here's the code for the javascript where I create the map, draw the polygon, capture the coordinates and send them to the form (also display the coordinates in a div which was originally meant to be for displaying the area):

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = (mymapboxkey);
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'mapid', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9', //hosted style id
    center: [-64.39027294716175,-34.600414379623835], // starting position
    zoom: 12, // starting zoom
});
 
var draw = new MapboxDraw({
    displayControlsDefault: false,
    controls: {
        polygon: true,
        trash: true,
    }
});
map.addControl(draw);
 
map.on('draw.create', updateArea);
map.on('draw.delete', updateArea);
map.on('draw.update', updateArea);
 
function updateArea(e) {
    var data = draw.getAll();
    var answer = document.getElementById('calculated-area');
    var ans = document.getElementById('poli')
    if (data.features.length > 0) {
        var area = turf.area(data);
        // restrict to area to 2 decimal points
        var rounded_area = Math.round(area * 100) / 100;
        var hectarea = rounded_area / 10000;
        val=data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
        dat=JSON.stringify(val);
        ans.value = dat;
        answer.innerHTML =
        '<p><strong>' + "dat "+
        dat +" val "+val+" area "+hectarea+
        '</strong></p><p>ha</p>';
        
    } else {
        answer.innerHTML = '';
        if (e.type !== 'draw.delete')
            alert('Use the draw tools to draw a polygon!');
    }
};
```

Here's the form where I'm sendindg the data:

```
<%= form_with(model: poligono, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if poligono.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(poligono.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this poligono from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% poligono.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :lote_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :lote_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :nombre %>
    <%= form.text_field :nombre %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:poligono, value = nil, html_options = {id: 'poli'}) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The "new" view where the form is rendered and the map is displayed:

```
<h1>New Poligono</h1>
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-top">
    <div class="cell small-2">
        <%= render 'form', poligono: @poligono %>

        <%= link_to 'Back', poligonos_path %>
    </div>

    <div class="cell small-10">
        <div id="mapid"></div>
        <div class="calculation-box">
            <p>Draw a polygon using the draw tools.</p>
            <div id="calculated-area"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'map'%>
```

and the controler:

```
class PoligonosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_poligono, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /poligonos
  # GET /poligonos.json
  def index
    @poligonos = Poligono.all
  end

  # GET /poligonos/1
  # GET /poligonos/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /poligonos/new
  def new
    @poligono = Poligono.new
    @poligono.lote= Lote.first
  end

  # GET /poligonos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /poligonos
  # POST /poligonos.json
  def create
    @poligono = Poligono.new(poligono_params)
   

    respond_to do |format|
      if @poligono.save
        format.html { redirect_to @poligono, notice: 'Poligono was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @poligono }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @poligono.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /poligonos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /poligonos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @poligono.update(poligono_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @poligono, notice: 'Poligono was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @poligono }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @poligono.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /poligonos/1
  # DELETE /poligonos/1.json
  def destroy
    @poligono.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to poligonos_url, notice: 'Poligono was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_poligono
      @poligono = Poligono.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def poligono_params
      params.require(:poligono).permit(:lote_id, :nombre, poligono:[])

    end
end
```

Please, if anyone can help me, I'll be very thankfull.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I was lacking rgeo gem an configuration. Now it's working fine.

Comment: Can you share the correct configuration that was causing the problem with `rgeo` gem? I'm creating an application with the same feature to draw and store and re-render polygons.

Comment: Sure, the problem was in the controller, in show and create. I'll post an answer below with the correct controller

Comment: That will be useful, thanks so much!
And by any chance, I need to let admins create polygons, and then when a client creates an order verify if the delivery address from the client, is within any polygon the admin created. Do you have any examples or suggestions to make it work?

Comment: Don't have any example, but it will be more efficient if you let postGIS do it, and not javascript (much faster). you should check ST_INTERSECT and ST_INTERSECTION

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the controller. The fixed controller, which made it work is the following:

```
class PoligonosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_poligono, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_lote
  # GET /poligonos
  # GET /poligonos.json
  def index
    @poligonos = Poligono.all
  end

  # GET /poligonos/1
  # GET /poligonos/1.json
  def show
    @poligono.polygon=RGeo::GeoJSON.encode(@poligono.polygon)
  end

  # GET /poligonos/new
  def new
    @poligono = Poligono.new
    
  end

  # GET /poligonos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /poligonos
  # POST /poligonos.json
  def create
    @poligono = Poligono.new(poligono_params)
    json=params[:polygon]
    feature = RGeo::GeoJSON.decode(json)
    @poligono.polygon=feature.geometry
    @poligono.lote_id = @lote.id
    @poligono.area = params[:area]
   
    
    if @poligono.save
      redirect_to campos_path, :notice => "El poligono ha sido agregado";
   else
      render "new";
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /poligonos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /poligonos/1.json
  def update
    if @lote.save()
      redirect_to campos_path, :notice => "El poligono ha sido modificado";
   else
      render "edit";
   end
  end

  # DELETE /poligonos/1
  # DELETE /poligonos/1.json
  def destroy
    @poligono.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to campos_url, notice: 'Poligono was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_lote
      @lote = Lote.find(params[:lote_id])
    end

    def set_poligono
      @poligono = Poligono.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def poligono_params
      params.require(:poligono).permit(:lote_id, :nombre, :area, :polygon)
      
    end
end
```